# Filter a Listbox based on 2 Combobox(es)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox, userform

[image]

So i'm very new to coding and want to learn how can i filter a listbox based on selection on 2 comboboxes. So what i want to do is when VBA initializes the entire range displays on the listbox and when 1 combobox is selected it filters down the range and when the second combobox is selected it filters down even more and both comboboxes can be used individually. but i couldnt find anything online either for VBA excel or something similar.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim Database(1 To 100, 1 To 4)
Dim my_range As Integer
Dim colum As Byte
On Error Resume Next

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")

sh.Range("G5").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Me.ComboBox1.Value



For i = 5 To sh.Range("G100000").End(xlUp).Row
If sh.Cells(i, 1) = Me.ComboBox1 Then

my_range = my_range + 1
For colum = 1 To 5
Database(my_range, colum) = sh.Cells(i, colum)

Next colum
End If
Next i
Me.ListBox1.List = Database
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()



With Me.ComboBox1
.Clear
.AddItem ""
.AddItem "L461"
.AddItem "L462"
.AddItem "L463"
.AddItem "L464"
.AddItem "L465"
 End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to SO. So basically the comboboxes contain filter criteria for what should be displayed in the listbox?

Comment: Yes, so for example the excel sheet itself has 10 columns and the 2 combobox will be based on 2 columns which will filter out.